# Android map API V2. GroundOverlays over Polygons

Tags: java, android, android-maps-v2

I am working on a mobile Android map of my university campus using Google's Android map API. I have currently used Polygons to color in each building according to their faculty. I have also placed GroundOverlays to show where each food place/ATM is. However, the Polygon's seem to lay on top of the Groundoverlays, but I want the opposite to happen. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you must use Zindex to change the layering of items:
put polygons without setting zIndex (or set a low value), then put ground overlay zIndex to hundreds (or thousands) and you are done!

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay.html#setZIndex(float)